# How to do logging in python in an explicit file

Tags: python, logging, fastapi, uvicorn

I tried below code only to find that my logs are getting printed in console.
What mistake I am doing here?

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="logger.log",
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                    filemode='w')
logger=logging.getLogger()

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info("An information")
```

I am running this code as a fastapi project via uvicorn server.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I run the code you have provided I get a file called `logger.log` containing `An information` with a timestamp, as expected.

Comment: which is why i thought the code is not wrong, but yet i am not getting any logger file

Comment: How are you running this code?

Comment: i am running it as a fastapi project via uvicorn server

Comment: As an alternative (not really solving your exact problem, per se), but be sure to check https://github.com/Delgan/loguru. It's a great library for logging, significantly simpler than the standard `logging` module.

Comment: Are you running inside a docker container ? I also ran your code and everything seemed fine (`logger.log` with the expected output)

Answer (score 3):

Pass the log level to run method

```
uvicorn.run("example:app", host='localhost', port=8000, reload=True, log_level='info')
```

Use logger

```
from uvicorn.config import logger
logger.info('Your Comment')
```

Comment: but this does not puts in file.